# Grafana Dashboard for Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, grafana, influxdb, influxql, grafana-variable

I am new to InfluxDB & Grafana. Currently we are performing load testing with Jmeter (5.2.1) and also utilizing InfluxDB (2.0) & Grafana for monitoring.
The set up goes like - 1 Controller machine and 8 remote host machines (LGs).

Though we are getting the value generated in the grafana dashboard, the development / project team is interested in knowing which LG is returning how much error and even we are interested to know, is the performance same on each of the loaf gen .

Question is - Do anyone here in community have configured the Grafana dashboard in a way that, we get individual graph for each of the host machine / LG.

*Already tried*

- Tried searching on google, but no suitable article found, if there is any, would request you to please share the link.
- Also observed that, though the jmeter result file (jtl) file contains the host machine IP under the header - threadName, but the same is not found in influxDB when the query select * from jmeter was executed.
  Does it means that, the threadName / host machine IP needs to be explicitly entered into DB with a separate sampler .. ? if so, how can this be achieved ?
- Tried building the query, but because of the limited knowledge in influxQL, not able to identify which keys / tags needs to be used

[Sample of jmeter output in JTL file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny3Xc.jpg)

If you can help on the building the dashboard, it would be of great help ..

Thanks in advance

Nike

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [Metrics Explosed](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics) chapter of the [Real-time results](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#realtime-results) user manual entry you won't see the "threadName" or similar metric anywhere.

It means that the name of the thread **isn't getting stored** in Graphite/InluxDB so there is no way to distinguish the load generator IP address in Grafana.

I can think of 2 possible options:

1. Modify existing relevant [AbstractBackendListenerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/AbstractBackendListenerClient.html) and add a separate measurement holding the IP address of the load generator machine
2. Add [__machineIP() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) as a prefix/postfix to your Sampler labels, in this case the sampler/transaction names will have the IP added and you will be able to filter them out in Grafana:

   [image]

   More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. I tried to insert the host name as suggested and am getting the host name in the thread name as well both - in JTL file and also in influx DB. However, i was still not able to create the dashboard based on this name. 
Seems like there needs to be separate tag. On exploring certain options, found that host name can be included in the JTL file as a header by configuring the listener from jmeter and enabling the option - "Save Hostname". 
Shall try this option and update the thread

Comment: - Update - 
the host name is now available in the JTL file by changing the property in the jmeter.properties file. however, this is not available as a TAG in grafana.. 
Can you please help me on how to get or configure a new tag in influxDB which serves as a input for grafana ?